# eliminate win10 network mapped driver disconnect delay

Tags: windows, networking, cifs

I have a smb server on linux, and I connect it using `net use` command on win10. When I monitor net traiffic using wireshark, I find that when using `net use Y: /delete` to disconnect the mapped drive, the actually disconnect will not immediately occur, and have a delay of about 5 seconds.  Linux client do not have this problem. This delay is a problem to me, because within the delay time, one can login without any authencation, which is a security risk in my software's use.

All I wish is, when I want to disconenct, just disconnect it, as what it does in linux, how to configure windows to fullfill this?

Comment: Did you try actually logging in with another user in between those 5 seconds?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I think you are right. I have tried before and windows share drive can only be seen by  user who connect it. So this may not be a problem if malware can not fake the system it is current user.